# How to make the button small

Tags: android

```
public class TabelaResultados extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_tabela_resultados);
        Bundle in = getIntent().getExtras();
        int numero = Integer.parseInt(in.getString("Numero"));

        if(in!=null) {
            for (int i = 0; i < numero; i++) {
                String tv1 = in.getString("Nome"+(i+1));
                TextView nome = new TextView(this);
                nome.setText(tv1);
                nome.setId(i+1);
                Button passou=new Button(this);
                passou.setText("LOL");
                passou.setLayoutParams(new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
                RelativeLayout layout= (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.tabelaLayout);
                RelativeLayout.LayoutParams params = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
                RelativeLayout.LayoutParams params2 = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);

                if(i == 0) {
                    params.addRule(RelativeLayout.BELOW, findViewById(R.id.tabelaLayout).getId());
                    nome.setPadding(0,0,0,30);
                    layout.addView(nome, params);
                    params2.addRule(RelativeLayout.RIGHT_OF,i+1);
                    params2.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_RIGHT,i+1);
                    layout.addView(passou,params2);


                } else {
                    params.addRule(RelativeLayout.BELOW, i);
                    layout.addView(nome, params);
                    params2.addRule(RelativeLayout.RIGHT_OF,i+1);
                    params2.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_RIGHT,i+1);
                    layout.addView(passou,params2);
                }


            }
        }
    }

}
```

How can I make the button smaller , to wrap content?
I've tried several solutions and none of them worked .
I'm kind of a noob in android developing ...
I want to do it dinamically because the number of buttons depends on the number os persons I add in the previous activity.
It stays like [This](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NkgL5.png)

EDIT: It's a relative layout.

Comment: You can use negative values for padding :)

Comment: can you show the xml?

Comment: It doesn't work because the textView on the left keeps following the button :s

Comment: <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"    android:id="@+id/tabelaLayout"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:orientation="vertical"
  tools:context="com.example.android.sobeedesce.TabelaResultados">
</RelativeLayout>

Answer (score 0):

Try replacing the original line with this:

```
passou.setLayoutParams(new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
```

If this doesn't work I'm not sure what your problem is.

Comment: Whoops, use "LinearLayout.LayoutParams".

Comment: The rest of your activity is a relative layout, but the button should be held by a linear layout. As long as your only change the button layout, the rest should stay the same.